# AsyncImage not displaying image URL when passed into view

Tags: swift, swiftui, asyncimageview

This child view is not displaying image URLs passed in from a parent view.
Child view:

```
struct PostImageView: View {

  var postImage: String

  var body: some View {
      AsyncImage(url: URL(string: postImage)) { image in
          image
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
      } placeholder: {
          Text("IMAGE URL: \(postImage)")
          ProgressView()
      }
      .ignoresSafeArea()
  }
}
```

- The `Text("IMAGE URL: \(postImage)")` is displaying the image URL on the view during loading state
- Adding a static image URL displays the image: `AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://url-to-image"))`

The parent view relies on an `ObservableObject` to determine when to display the view containing `AsyncImage`:

```
class ImageDetail: ObservableObject {
    @Published var imageUrl = ""
    @Published var showImageDetail: Bool = false
}
```

This part of the parent view then navigates to the child view and passes the image URL:

```
 NavigationLink(destination: PostImageView(postImage: imageDetail.imageUrl), isActive: $imageDetail.showImageDetail) {
    EmptyView()
 }
```

When `showImageDetail` is `true`, the `imageUrl` value contains a valid image URL, which is then passed into the `PostImageView` containing `AsyncImage`.

The `imageUrl` value is being successfully passed as per the `Text("IMAGE URL: \(postImage)")` output mentioned above.

Comment: Thing to note is that right now `AsyncImagePhase` has only `.empty` phase for both `nil` URLs (when  `AsyncImage` does't try to fetch anything - which is reasonable) and for the period when `AsyncImage` actually tries to fetch data.
This is rather inconvenient because it takes one more step to check why the image is empty and either show "ProgressView" or placeholder "no image".

Answer (score 3):

After some testing, it appears that `AsyncImage` is silently failing when an insecure `http` URL is passed in from the parent.

I've resolved this by adding a function to detect insecure http URLs and convert them to https URLs instead.

Strangely, there is an explicit error about not allowing insecure URLs when using a static URL within the child view, but not when passing from parent.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to use http instead of https, it's necessary to change NSAppTransportSecurity in you info.plist

- How to: [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

But, looks like you've managed to solve the problem without using http, which is better.